# jQuery UI syntax error when closing selectmenu with a special character (%) in ID selector

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I have a selectmenu that is throwing the following error when I click outside of the menu (or explicitly close the menu)

```
Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression : .ui-selectmenu-menu, #My%20System_input-button
    at Function.fa.error (http://localhost:8081/jquery/jquery-2.2.4.min.js:2:12556)
    at fa.tokenize (http://localhost:8081/jquery/jquery-2.2.4.min.js:2:18609)
    at fa.compile (http://localhost:8081/jquery/jquery-2.2.4.min.js:2:21240)
    at fa.select (http://localhost:8081/jquery/jquery-2.2.4.min.js:2:21948)
    at fa (http://localhost:8081/jquery/jquery-2.2.4.min.js:2:7143)
    at Function.fa.matchesSelector (http://localhost:8081/jquery/jquery-2.2.4.min.js:2:12175)
    at n.fn.init.closest (http://localhost:8081/jquery/jquery-2.2.4.min.js:2:25517)
    at $.(anonymous function).(anonymous function).mousedown (http://localhost:8081/jquery/jquery-ui-1.11.4.js:12549:28)
    at HTMLDocument.handlerProxy (http://localhost:8081/jquery/jquery-ui-1.11.4.js:726:7)
    at HTMLDocument.dispatch (http://localhost:8081/jquery/jquery-2.2.4.min.js:3:7537)
```

It seems from my Googling that this is likely an issue with the % in the ID selector in the following function in jquery-ui-1.11.4. I tracked this function down with the error trace

```
_documentClick: {
    mousedown: function( event ) {
        if ( !this.isOpen ) {
            return;
        }

        if ( !$( event.target ).closest( ".ui-selectmenu-menu, #" + this.ids.button ).length ) {
            this.close( event );
        }
    }
},
```

Is there any way around this or do I just have to figure out a better ID to use for my element?

Comment: @Kaddath the space encoding is actually something I do programmatically because that part of the ID is based on a user configurable field, which allows for spaces. I think my best route forward is just to make the ID not based on the configurable field to be honest. I was using it as a uniqueness factor but I might need to rethink that approach. I don't want to edit the jquery javascript to handle things specifically for this situation either.

Comment: You should remember this golden rule if you want to avoid such issues, DON'T EVER USE A WHITE SPACE IN NAMING YOUR IDs. USE AN UNDERSCORE INSTEAD TO SEPARATE WORDS.